# Set up a SQL Server database based on an Excel file which refreshes automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, data-synchronization, excel

Can I set up a Server database based on an Excel file, which refreshes automatically with any changes in the source Excel file?

I am currently using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? You can use `openrowset` to update / upload data from excel to sql server database. Also, Phil Factor has an excellent article on [Getting Data between Excel and SQL Server using ODBC](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/getting-data-between-excel-and-sql-server-using-odbc--/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes) which triggers when the Excel file changes and runs simple code to push the revised file through to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. There are many different ways to achieve it - but I would suggest the following rough steps using SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services).

- Create the SQL database that will hold the data from Excel, and add a table to it with the structure that you want.
- Install an SSIS File Watcher Task, such as this one: http://www.sqlis.com/post/file-watcher-task.aspx  on both your development and production servers.
- Using "SQL Server Data Tools" (or Business Intelligence Development Studio as it used to be known) create a new SSIS project, and within that, an SSIS package.
- Add an Excel data source connection, and a SQL data destination connection.
- Add an Execute SQL Task to truncate your existing data from the table
- Add a Data Flow task, to import the data from Excel to the table. 
  (Get these two steps working before proceeding any further.)
- Add in the File Watcher Task and configure it.
- Deploy the database & package to your production server and get it working there
- Build a SQL Agent job to run the package on a schedule that takes into account the nature of the File Watcher Task.